# Add page child button needs to be effective only on first level

Tags: django, wagtail

On click "Add page child" I want to be able to add a page only when I'm on the first level (homepage). The page model doesn't need to be selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can control where can pages be inserted with `parent_page_types` and `subpage_types` (see [documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12.1/topics/pages.html#parent-page-subpage-type-rules))

For example, the following will only allow the `ChildPage` to be created underneath the `HomePage`.

```
class ChildPage(Page):
    parent_page_type = ['my_app.HomePage']
```

Comment: Please mark it as the correct answer then, so people know that this issue has been resolved.